# Filling an HTML drop down box from database using php, but I'm missing one record

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu, mysqli

I'm pulling rows from a mysql database to fill a drop down box. It works, but it misses out one option. I think it might be due to the fact I'm using the `<optgroup>` tag in the middle, where the option would be - in fact if I remove this, the whole list is printed.
My database has data similar to below:

```
Module Code|Module Name
-----------|-------------
SE1AA11    |Animal Acting
SE1BB11    |Boring Billiards
  ...      |     ...
SE2AA11    |Animal Archery
SE2BB11    |Boring Boxes
  ...      |     ...
```

(`...` indicates more data and yes, the module names are made up)

When the page loads, it misses out the first of the SE2 options. Any ideas why? Any help would be appreciated. Code below:

```
<select name="module1" id="module1" style="display: none;">
<option value="" selected disabled>Module 1</option>
<?php 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Modules";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo '<optgroup label="Part One">';

while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) && 
      (substr($row['ModuleCode'], 0, -4) == "SE1")){
$code = $row['ModuleCode'];
$name = $row['ModuleName']; 
echo '<option value="'.$code.'">' . $name . '</option>';
}
echo '</optgroup>';

echo '<optgroup label="Part Two">';
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) && 
      (substr($row['ModuleCode'], 0, -4) == "SE2")){
$code = $row['ModuleCode'];
$name = $row['ModuleName']; 
echo '<option value="'.$code.'">' . $name . '</option>';
}
echo '</optgroup>';
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Please DO NOT fill anything from database but learn to use **templates** instead.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Why? Even Smarty in there use cases page states that for small projects or 1 person shops it's probably better not to use a template.

Comment: Stack Overflow is the *only* place on the Earth where you can see a question "why use templates" in XXI century...

Comment: I've changed completely now by taking it out of the `<optgroup>` tags altogether and labelling a different way. Still interested to know what was wrong with the code though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss out one record because of this: when your first while loop has iterated over all SE1* records, it does another call to `mysqli_fetch_array()` which fetches the next record from your result set. This record does not comply with your second condition (it does not start with 'SE1') so PHP moves to the next while loop, where another call is made to `mysqli_fetch_array()` which will fetch the next record from your result set.

Because your first 'SE2*' item was already fetched by the first loop, but never processed by that loop, you will not see that record back in your dropdown list.